# How can I apply a function to several images in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, getelementbyid, grayscale

I need a little help with (probably) something really simple.

I want to use a script which converts images from color to grayscale.
I got it working partially — the first image turns gray, but the second won’t.

I know this is because an id cannot be used multiple times:

```
var imgObj = document.getElementById('grayimage');
```

I tried this:

```
var imgObj = $(’.grayimage’)[0];
```

But it didn’t work. Changing it to `getElementByClass` also does not work. (Before people ask, I did change the `id` to class in the `<img>` tag.)

I really could use some help here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `$(’.grayimage’)` returns a list of all objects of class `grayimage`.  `$(’#grayimage’)` returns the object with ID `grayimage`.  So the first question you have to answer is if `grayImage` should be a class (there are multiple grayImages) or an ID (there is only ever one grayImage per page).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.grayimage').each(function(idx,imgObj){
    <do your code here>
});
```

Comment: Hmm this works halfway. I mean it works in IE, but does not in FF and chrome.

Comment: that is because only IE supports filters, grayscaling images in firefox and chrome isn't possible without using canvas

Comment: ok so i reuploaded the code, can you tell me what i did wrong or what to change? I dont have a lot of knowledge of Javascript

Comment: the problem is that you cant grayscale images using javascript. Internet explorer offers filters which can manipulate your images but firefox and chrome don't. This means that if it works in IE, you're done, since you can't use it in firefox and chrome.

Comment: But i think it is possible with canvas. I included canvas. i got the script from here: http://www.ajaxblender.com/article-sources/jquery/convert-image-grayscale/index.html as you can see this works in FF and chrome, i cannot see what i am doing wrong... but then again i dont understand javascript to well. BTW: not that i include jquery.

Comment: based on the assumption that you aren't too good with javascript, i hadn't thought about the canvas trick. its pretty easy though: create canvas with size of image, copy image into canvas, run grayscaling algorithm on canvas, replace image with canvas. done :-) however: canvas isn't supported by IE so you would need to use the filter method for IE

Answer (score 2):

$('.grayimage') gives you a list of all elements with grayimage as a class.  If you add '[0]' you're accessing the first element, so any changes you make will apply to only the first image that it finds with this class.

You should loop through all elements:

```
var images = $('.grayimage');
for(i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
   var image = images[i];

   // Do stuff
}
```